# <div> changes location when inserted with content

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make 3 box layout with first box being a login form, whenever I insert a sign up form into my first div, my first div jumps down bellow other divs. I want all of my divs on the same horizontal line, with the first one containing a sign up form,any ideas how I could achieve this?

Below I have inserted my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.firstmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.secondmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: red;
}

.thirdmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bandau {
  border: 2px black solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstmenu">
  <div class="secondmenu">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="LastName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thirdmenu"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your first menu should not contain your second menu if you want them side by side.  With inline-block use float:left to get the alignment you want. also reverse the order of first and second menu if you want the form on the left.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.firstmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.secondmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: red;
}

.thirdmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bandau {
  border: 2px black solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="secondmenu">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="LastName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="firstmenu">fm</div>

<div class="thirdmenu"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't explaine behavior, but if add `firstmenu` to class `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` to class `secondmenu` it fix the issue.

Look in snippet in full screen mode.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.firstmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  position: relative; /*added*/
}

.secondmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute; /*added*/
}

.thirdmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bandau {
  border: 2px black solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstmenu">
  <div class="secondmenu">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="LastName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thirdmenu"></div>
```

Second variant to add `position: relative;` to class `secondmenu` and `position: absolute;` to `form`, slightly different variant and look.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.firstmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.secondmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative; /*added*/
}

.secondmenu form {
  position: absolute; /*added*/
}

.thirdmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bandau {
  border: 2px black solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstmenu">
  <div class="secondmenu">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
      <input class="bandau" type="text" name="LastName" value="Įvesta reišmė">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thirdmenu"></div>
```